# Bootstrap carousel-control is getting under an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the default carousel from bootstrap since i am starting with it, I have three items in my html file. One of them is this:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="active item">
            <div id="labamba">
                <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div id="labamba">
                <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div id="labamba">
                <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="Cover">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


    <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> </a>
    <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>
</div>
```

I wanted to make my carousel have many items and not only a big image with caption i was trying to ad divs, however i noticed when i put a big image it covered the carousel-control i do not know why. can someone help me out?

CSS overridden:

```
#myCarousel {
    background-color: #222;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 0;
}

#labamba {
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    position: absolute;
    left: 15%;
    right: 15%;
    bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

Why the carousel-control has too much height and width? can i just resize it only for the arrow size? i do not know how to do it because when i modify the css it changes the position like if it was a big image and not the arrow only.

I am using Bootstrap 3.3 the github version, i think it is the latest one, i havent modified anything. Thanks for your help.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the z-index: 11; and position: relative on #myCarousel styling.

Post a link to your bootstrap css and I will be able to help you with the 2nd issue.

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: bootstrap 3.3, and it worked but i had to delete z-indes: 10px; from #labamba, what about the second question? i really need help for the second question :X

Comment: Add this to your css:


.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 15px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .5;
}

Comment: thanks it worked, could you explain me why it wasn't working for me? i was modifying the height and width and it didn't worked for me

Comment: Because .carousel-control top was set to 0 and line height was not set by default in bootstrap 3.3